# Thin border when using CAShapeLayer as mask for CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer

In Swift, I have two semi-transparent circles, both of which are `CAShapeLayer`. Since they are semi-transparent, any overlap between them becomes visible like so:

[image]

Instead, I want them to visually "merge" together. The solution I have tried is to use circle 2 as a mask for circle 1, therefore cutting away the overlap.

This solution is generally working, but I get a thin line on the outside of circle 2:

[image]

## My question: How can I get rid of the thin, outside line on the right circle? Why is it even there?

---

The code is as follows ([Xcode playground can be found here](https://ufile.io/k282x)):

```
    private let yPosition: CGFloat = 200
    private let circle1Position: CGFloat = 30
    private let circle2Position: CGFloat = 150
    private let circleDiameter: CGFloat = 200
    private var circleRadius: CGFloat { return self.circleDiameter/2.0 }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black

        self.view = view

        let circle1Path = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: CGRect(
                x: circle1Position,
                y: yPosition,
                width: circleDiameter,
                height: circleDiameter),
            cornerRadius: self.circleDiameter)

        let circle2Path = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: CGRect(
                x: circle2Position,
                y: yPosition,
                width: circleDiameter,
                height: circleDiameter),
            cornerRadius: self.circleDiameter)

        let circle1Layer = CAShapeLayer()
        circle1Layer.path = circle1Path.cgPath
        circle1Layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor

        let circle2Layer = CAShapeLayer()
        circle2Layer.path = circle2Path.cgPath
        circle2Layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(circle1Layer)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(circle2Layer)

        //Create a mask from the surrounding rectangle of circle1, and
        //then cut out where it overlaps circle2
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: circle1Position, y: yPosition, width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter))
        maskPath.append(circle2Path)
        maskPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        maskPath.lineWidth = 0

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        circle1Layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```

Comment: The thin line is almost certainly antialiasing

Comment: I had the same thought - any way to control aliasing in this case?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but you could draw the shape above using two arcs instead of trying to merge two circles.

Comment: Don't think so. You're trying to draw partial pixels. My only real thought here is to calculate the intersection points of the circles and vertically cut both circles at that point using masks, so that way you have two partial-circles next to each other rather than one full circle and one partially-occluded circle. But even that will only work right if the vertical cut is on a pixel boundary, otherwise you'll probably still have antialiasing artifacts.

Comment: A foolproof approach would be to detect that the circles overlap and switch to using a single shape layer that draws a single path that describes the merged circles.

Comment: Alternatively, if the background color is a constant, you could premultiply your alpha and draw fully-opaque circles instead, at which point overlapping wouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is what I was afraid of :/ non-transparent background is not an option, unfortunately, so I guess I have to switch to a single shape. Going to be ugly, since this is part of an interactive control, but if it's the only way...

Comment: @Sparky They circles are different parts of an interactive element and might or might not overlap, which makes things a bit more difficult. But I think the final solution will be something in that direction, yes.

Comment: Are you trying to animate this? As in: have the circles start at left right and animated toward the center, overlapping as needed?

Comment: @DonMag The circle positions are controlled by the user, but generally you could say that I do

Comment: I think the maths will be ugly, certainly! You probably need to keep track of the centre of each circle, and then in your drawing code check if the circles overlap as per @KevinBallard 's comment; if they do, you then need some maths to work out the start and end angle for each arc (is the shape always going to be symmetric? If so, that will simplify things). Good luck!

Comment: You could also switch to using `drawRect(_:)` to draw the circles instead of shape layers. Then this becomes easy; set your alpha, begin a transparency layer on your context, draw both circles fully-opaque into the layer, then end the layer, and it will composite that layer back into the context at the previously-set alpha. This way you won't have to worry about whether the circles overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If both CAShapeLayers have the same alpha value, you could place them inside a new parent CALayer then set the alpha of the parent instead.